# How To Effectively Graph This Data Using Excel

Tags: excel, graph

I'd like to create an appropriate graph for the following sort of data. I'm using an example as the actual data is 1000+ lines.

```
Date         Player       Points

02/06/2014   Bob          2500
03/06/2014   Bob          4000
04/06/2014   Bob          5100
02/06/2014   Steve        1000
03/06/2014   Steve        1500
04/06/2014   Steve        3600
02/06/2014   Sam          5000
03/06/2014   Sam          3700
04/06/2014   Sam          4100
```

I'd like the graph to track each player's progress over time. Ideally a line graph. I am having trouble with excel trying to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the data above to generate a pivot table. Put the date in the Rows Area, the player in the Columns Area, and the Points in the Data Area. This will give you a column of values for each player.

Make a pivot chart from the pivot table. Each player will be plotted separately in the chart.